# CAN I ENTER FRANCE

Tags: visas

I have schengen visa (tourist) issued by swiss embassy,  with single entry,  one month  visa.
can I enter france (wish to go to paris from Geneva by train)  after I complete my 10 days stay in Switzerland ?

Comment: What's the duration of stay allowed by your visa?